# how to add manual intervention in build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

i have a build pipeline i want to add mannual intervention in the pipeline and when that manual intervention is done the user can click on resume the pipeline but i want to do this in build pipeline.

i checked in this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml but it looks like we need to do using stage pipeline in release pipeline. but i want this to happen in build pipeline

Answer (score 7):

We seem have not such task for build pipeline, especially classic build pipeline.

If you want to add manual intervention in a build pipeline, you can try to set up this pipeline with YAML and add this run the **Manual Validation task** in an agentless job.

However, it might not be possible if you want to pause a running agent job in the build pipeline. Maybe you can try run the pipeline on a self-hosted agent with [interactive mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service).

**[UPDATE]**

You should use the **Manual Validation task** in an agentless job in the YAML pipeline, not in the classic build pipeline.

To set up an agentless job in the YAML pipeline, you need to set the value of '**pool**' key to ne '**server**'.

```yaml
jobs:
- job: agentless-job
  pool: server
```

To view more details, you can see "[Server jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#server-jobs)".

Comment: How do i add manual validation task in build pipeline when i tried that i get the error as Step  references task 'ManualValidation' at version '0.179.0' which is not valid for the given job target.

Comment: Also how can i run an agentless job in build pipeline?

Comment: Hi @ashish, I have updated my answer with more details, please check it.

Answer (score -1):

To add a manual validation task in pipeline without creating a agent-less job you will need to define pool: server on the top of your steps. as below.
I got this from by referring to canary deployments but have tested the same works for rolling deployment and probably other steps introduced in the pipeline.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops

```
pool: server    
steps:
- task: ManualValidation@0
  timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
  inputs:
    notifyUsers: |
       youremailadress@hotmail.com
  instructions: 'Please validate the build configuration and resume'
  onTimeout: 'reject'
```